# find history of mysql commands on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, mysql

i use mysql on ubuntu.i find all last commands history on terminal by **history** command but it exclude **mysql query or commands**.is there any method or command like **history** to find last mysql queries history on ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those commands go into `~/.mysql_history`.

Comment: If you consider my answer acceptable, please click the tick mark next to the question to mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

If you logged into mysql CLI with `sudo`, it might actually be at the following location:

```
/root/.mysql_history
```

In any case, the following `find` command can help you:

```
sudo find / -name .mysql_history
```